# Parameterize functions with classes and access class members

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters

I'm wondering how exactly this code works in detail (e.g. how is it able to directly access the value of TYPE).

I saw this code in a larger codebase (which is non-public, so the example is paraphrased). I've never seen this specific use-case. Is passing a template parameter like this common? Does it have a specific name/is this an idiom/pattern? When would you use this and why?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace FileA
{
struct Foo
{
    enum TYPE
    {
        ENTRY,
    };

    void callme()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};
}

namespace FileB
{
template <typename T>
void fun(T& obj)
{
    std::cout << T::ENTRY << "\n";
    obj.callme();
}
}

int main()
{
    FileA::Foo f;
    FileB::fun(f);
}
```

This will print:

```
0
Foo
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is... This is a template function that accesses members of the given object/type. It only compiles if those members exist. This is all how templates are supposed to behave, and using them like this is not uncommon...

Comment: Basically, remove the `template<>` stuff and replace `T` with `FileA::Foo`. Does any of the resulting code and behavior surprise you? If yes, that has nothing to do with templates. If no, the above substitution is all the compiler does to instantiate the template.

Comment: @user463035818 Trailing `,` in enum definitions are [definitely ok](https://godbolt.org/z/Ktrvzu).

Comment: @MaxLanghof hm ok then I already learned something for today. And, sorry @ OP ;)

Comment: your questions are rather unclear, there is no name for this "idiom". Actually its not clear what you consider as special about this code that it deserves a name, maybe you can explain more? "Is passing a template parameter like this common? " how else would you pass a template parameter?

Comment: is it possible that what confuses you is that the template code expects the type to have certain properties as opposed to more general templates along the line of `template <typename T> T add(T a,T b){ return a+b;}` ?

Comment: @MaxLanghof If the compiler simply replaces it with `FileA::Foo` anyways then what is the point of writing it with the template stuff? Isn't this just making things more complicated for no apparent gain?

Comment: No, it is so you can use `fun` with multiple different types without duplicating code. That's the #1 purpose of templates. If there is only exactly one use of `fun` in the entire code base then it is probably more complicated than it needs to be (unless it is part of the public interface of some library for others to use). But there are probably more uses of `fun`, not only with `FileA::Foo` but multiple other types.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That makes sense. However if you never call it with more than one type there is no advantage correct?

Comment: In this case that is correct, yes (again assuming that no outside user gets to call it either). There are other cases where template functions make sense even if they are only called once (e.g. pack expansion, SFINAE, or resolving overload ambiguities), but you really shouldn't worry about those at this point.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Got it, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

a template is a kind of macro in the general sense of the term, so if you *"expand"* `FileB::fun(f);` T is replaced by the type of *f* being `FileA::Foo` and it is like if you have :

```
void fun(FileA::Foo& obj)
{
    std::cout << FileA::Foo::ENTRY << "\n";
    obj.callme();
}
```

because `FileA::Foo::ENTRY` is 0 the *std::cout* writes 0, then you apply `FileA::Foo::callme()` whose prints *Foo*

*Warning, a template is much more than that, it is just a very simplified explanation of how that example works and produces the outputs, do not take it literally please ^^*

Comment: It's not clear if the question relates to that too, but because of the wording "passing template parameters like this" I would also say a few words about template argument deduction...

Comment: @MaxLanghof is just a way to explain for someone who doesn't know what a template is, do not take this at the foot of the letter please ^^

Comment: "is a kind of macro" I think I know what you mean, but still it hurts a bit to read this :P. I'd say the most important difference is that the compiler knows about templates, but knows nothing about macros

Comment: @user463035818 Is the preprocessor not part of the compiler?

Comment: @MaxLanghof for that matter I prefer to see the preprocessor as something seperate that does its job before the compiler gets to see the code

Comment: Guy please, open your mind ^^ the first thing to say about template is not to enter in all the complicated details and to explode the brain of the people seeing the use of a template for the first time, no ?

Comment: @MaxLanghof the imporant difference is just that you will not get a compiler error for a wrongly written macro, but you will get (possibly highly confusing) errors for the expanded code only

Comment: @bruno macros are complicated details that I would try to keep away from beginners much longer than templates. Anyhow, this is just nitpicking...

Comment: @user463035818 If your compiler doesn't help you trace code generated from macros, you might want to switch/upgrade compilers. Don't get me wrong, they can't magically deobfuscate deeply nested macros, but [basic troubleshooting](https://godbolt.org/z/PBenwR) is definitely in the realm of possibility.

Comment: @bruno "au pied de la lettre" is not an expression that works the same way in English (I don't think most people would understand what you mean, except from context). If anything, it's left untranslated (like "raison d'être"), but that would sound way too pompous here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof is not "raison d'être" at all, I used google trans ^^

Comment: @bruno No, I meant that "raison d'être" is a french expression that you will find untranslated in English text. Not that it is equivalent to "au pied de la lettre".

Comment: @MaxLanghof I mean "do not take it literally", I edited, thank you for the advice

Comment: **I I suspected that there would be shouting with my answer, it does not matter if it allowed the OP to move forward ^^**